# reactjs ensure parent child relationship

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I've created two elements -- Parent and Child

Is there a way to ensure that the child element is contained by parent?  I want to ensure that the DOM always looks like --

```jsx
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

and never

```jsx
<SomeOtherElement>
    <Child />
</SomeOtherElement>
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do that, but probably let parent pass a key as prop to child, and let child render only if that key is available?

Comment: I agree with @octref there might not be any reason for you to do that. Plus you're breaking reusability of the Child element. If that's what you want, you might not need a Child element at all and just work with the Parent which, in that case, will also contain everything Child renders.

Comment: I'm spending some time learning reactjs, and have been using reactjs to render the material design lite components (http://goo.gl/J0AN52).  In particular, the Card Title should always be a child of Card.  There is no reusability of the title, it must be a child.  I'd like to check this relationship if possible, if not it's not that big of a deal really..